Tkinter unable to close secondary window
I have a main window open. I don't want to close this window. (which seems to be in most of these questions).
when I click on a button a small window opens under the mouse position. I want this second window to close when either one of its buttons are pressed or after the mouse moves away.
My problem is when I go into a function from either of the above actions I do not seem to have a reference to close this window. as in 'alt.destroy'
My thought is to use the mouse moves away option as it should cover all needs.
Here is a sample code of what I am trying to do.
from tkinter import * 
backGd='#333333'
FrGd='white'
def AlignmentTypes():
    alt_x_y=ListWinStartPsn()       
    alt = Tk()
    alt.geometry(f"100x150+{alt_x_y[0]}+{alt_x_y[1]+20}")
    #alt.configure(bg=backGd)
    alt.bind("<Leave>", closeAltWin)

    Titlelabel=Label(alt, text="Select Alignment Type",bg=backGd,fg=FrGd)
    alLeft_btn=Button(alt,text="Align Left",fg="Dark Blue",width=11)
    alCenter_btn=Button(alt,text="Align Center",fg="Dark Blue",width=11)
    alRight_btn=Button(alt,text="Align Right",fg="Dark Blue",width=11)
    alJustify_btn=Button(alt,text="Align Justify",fg="Dark Blue",width=11)
        
    Titlelabel.pack()
    alLeft_btn.pack()
    alCenter_btn.pack()
    alRight_btn.pack()
    alJustify_btn.pack()

def ListWinStartPsn():
    x, y = btn1.winfo_rootx(), btn1.winfo_rooty()
    return(x,y)

def closeAltWin(event):
    pass
    #alt.destroy

root = Tk()
root.title('Workopedia')
root.geometry('500x300')


frame1=Frame(root)
frame1.pack()
btn1=Button(frame1,text="click",command=AlignmentTypes)
btn1.pack()
frame2=Frame(root)
frame2.pack()
lbl1=Label(frame1,text="Stuff")
lbl1.pack()

root.mainloop()


Should be alt = Toplevel() instead of alt = Tk()

import * is not preferred. Preferred are lower_case_names for functions and variables. See more: PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code

Closing the second window while leaving it is not possible as it is a default behavior. But when the second window is open, if you enter into the first window, the second window can be closed.
The difference between the above two is: leaving the second window means(or leaving any window) when the second window is open, when you switch to any other program in your computer(either with alt + tab or using mouse), Even this is leaving the second window. This is because : When you're working in the second window, suddenly if you get any phone call and you want to change to new program in your computer to take the detail, You can't save and close the window, go to another window and come back. So, it is designed in such a way the window can't be closed without any action by the user.
Entering the first window is almost like leaving the second window. Only thing if you move your mouse to the first window, when the second window is open, then the second window will close. Only thing, If you move the mouse to some other position of your desktop but not to the first window, then the second window won't close.
The following code will close the second window if you press any of the buttons in the second window or if you enter first window
from tkinter import * 
backGd='#333333'
FrGd='white'

# declaring a dict as I don't want to declare root as global variable
dct = {}
def AlignmentTypes():

    # we already defined as dct['window'] is root. But giving a variable name for dct['window']
    # Let the name of the variable be 'root' again for the sake of convenience.
   
    root = dct['window']  

    #The functions are defined in the second window so that these functions can be accessed by 2nd window.
    def close_window(*event):
    
        #Unbind root with '<Enter>'  to avoid error while moving the mouse to root window after the 2nd window is closed        
        root.bind('<Enter>', lambda e:'break')
        
        #Close the second winsow
        alt.destroy()
        
    # This function also defned inside the second window as it is used in 2nd window    
    def ListWinStartPsn():
        x, y = btn1.winfo_rootx(), btn1.winfo_rooty()
        return(x,y)
    
    alt_x_y=ListWinStartPsn()       
    alt = Tk()
    alt.geometry(f"100x150+{alt_x_y[0]}+{alt_x_y[1]+20}")
    #alt.configure(bg=backGd)
    
    # map all the buttons with the function close_window
    Titlelabel=Label(alt, text="Select Alignment Type",bg=backGd,fg=FrGd)
    alLeft_btn=Button(alt,text="Align Left",fg="Dark Blue",width=11, command = close_window)
    alCenter_btn=Button(alt,text="Align Center",fg="Dark Blue",width=11, command = close_window)
    alRight_btn=Button(alt,text="Align Right",fg="Dark Blue",width=11, command = close_window)
    alJustify_btn=Button(alt,text="Align Justify",fg="Dark Blue",width=11, command = close_window)
        
    Titlelabel.pack()
    alLeft_btn.pack()
    alCenter_btn.pack()
    alRight_btn.pack()
    alJustify_btn.pack()
    
    # Bind root, <Enter> with the function close_window.
    root.bind('<Enter>', close_window)  

root = Tk()
root.title('Workopedia')
root.geometry('500x300')

# to avoid global vaiable, make root as a value of the dict
dct['window'] = root


frame1=Frame(root)
frame1.pack()
btn1=Button(frame1,text="click",command=AlignmentTypes)
btn1.pack()
frame2=Frame(root)
frame2.pack()
lbl1=Label(frame1,text="Stuff")
lbl1.pack()

root.mainloop()


Thank you perfect I appreciate everyone's input


when I click on a button a small window opens under the mouse
position. I want this second window to close when either one of its
buttons are pressed or after the mouse moves away.

The problem can be fixed.
On line 6, change this alt = Tk() to : alt = Toplevel()
In closeAltWin function, add this root.winfo_children()
Snippet:
def closeAltWin(event):
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(widget, Toplevel):
            widget.destroy()


My thought is to use the mouse moves away option as it should cover
all needs.

As you can see, the mouse moved away. Will destroy the second window.
Screenshot:


You can check whether the widget that trigger the event <Leave> is a toplevel, if yes, then destroy the widget:
def closeAltWin(event):
    if event.widget.winfo_toplevel() is event.widget:
        # the widget that triggers the event is a toplevel window
        # so destroy it
        event.widget.destroy()

Note that as other said, it is better to use Toplevel() instead of Tk() for child windows.

So I needed to set alt as global
by adding global alt in the AlignmentTypes(): function as:
def AlignmentTypes():
        global alt

Now my only problem is it closes after leaving any widget on the window . I want it to only be on leaving the window.
If anyone has an idea on that I would still appreciate it

This should either be an edit to your current question, or posted as a new question with a link back to this question for context (if appropriate. SO works a bit differently to other sites, it doesn't have threads. Just one question per post. Thanks
